# Upload img without using submit button or rederict in PHP & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This might look like a duplicate but I have not found something that matches my needs exactly yet. I want to upload an Image to a folder by just choosing a file in the file browser, no submit button used (so far so good, i can do this). But then I want the user not be redirected the to `upload.php` file.
So I need to submit a file without a using submit button and not redirecting the user to another page. A refresh is ok but preferable without refresh as well.. 
This is what i have right now, and my question is if this could be done in `PHP,AJAX & Javascript` or if i should go for a `JQuery plugin`?

AND I will have several forms so i am not using ID-tag

My code so far doesn't work 100%, only when i upload and redirect to `upload.php` :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="test">
</form>

    $(".test").change(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data('file', $(this[0].files[0])),
            success: function(text) {
                    alert("successfully");
            }
        });   
    });
```

**UPLOAD.PHP**

```
<?php if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/myfile.jpg")) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
 } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
 }?>
```

Comment: Yes you can do it with ajax. If you need uploaded file list, you can make another ajax call inside first ajax success event. Then use `append()` or `prepend()` to add current result. Or you can use `html()` to completely change the page / div content.

Comment: Ok @Nikko that sounds good, my issue right now is that im not getting a success response, think that my data use is off somehow?

Comment: I didn't aware about the data on your AJAX call. You should check the link from Girish to upload file with AJAX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image immediately after file is selected, rather than force user to click separate "Upload" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509032/how-to-upload-image-immediately-after-file-is-selected-rather-than-force-user-t)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) because it takes care of browser versions and operating systems compatibility issues. If you don't need anything advanced read this [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)

Code from the above link

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Edited based on OP comment:

```
$(function () {
    $('.fileuploads').each(function(i, obj){
        $(obj).fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this way is that I have several Forms and have to use class-identifier for upload..

Comment: do you know how to use data-url="server/php/" ? what should it point to?

Comment: you are using angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method without button click and refresh page file upload.

```
<form id="uploadform" target="upiframe" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="test" onchange="yourFunction()">
</form>

<iframe id="upiframe" name="upiframe" witdh="0px" height="0px" border="0" style="width:0; height:0; border:none;"></iframe>


function yourFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById('uploadform');
    form.submit();
  });
}
```